# Android: How to receive the intent when download a file completely by browser?

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I can receive the intent of "android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" from DownloadManager which I implement, but I can't receive it when download a file by browser. Dose anyone know how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions you are trying , I don't think so its possible. The Possible solutions you should try is use File Observer , Which basically does :

Monitors files (using inotify) to fire an event after files are accessed or changed by by any process on the device (including this one). FileObserver is an abstract class; subclasses must implement the event handler onEvent(int, String).

Each FileObserver instance monitors a single file or directory. If a directory is monitored, events will be triggered for all files and subdirectories inside the monitored directory.

An event mask is used to specify which changes or actions to report. Event type constants are used to describe the possible changes in the event mask as well as what actually happened in event callbacks.

You should download the file in directory where you have registered the FileObserver to look for all the events from your app and get the event notification accordingly

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the File Observer can't achieve my purpose completely. Because its event codes are hard to recognize if the file is downloaded completely.

Comment: For example, when I start download a file. the event code will be as follow:
Event = 256
Event = 32
Event = 2
Event = 8
Event = 32
Event = 2
Event = 8
Event = 32
Event = 2
Event = 8
Event = 32
Event = 2
Event = 8
...(repeat 32 > 2 > 8)

The last event code usually will be 8 ,but I don't know the download is done even I take the file size to consider.

Comment: So looking at the code - 256 - Create , 32 - Open, 2- Modify , 8 - Close Write. Can't you write logic around these events. You can try various options like Rename a File , Move this file etc. You will get the different events for these operation. so in this case you can put an assumption that for when you get Event 256 , then till you get the last Event 8. Means your file is downloaded.

Comment: Mmm...it is not so easy, because I don't know which Event 8 is the last one. But still thanks for your response.

Comment: BTW you won't get any specific event for your file download. I had implemented it at same way. There I use to listen for diff events